# Replace all 'NA' with 0 in complete DT (Python Datatable)

Tags: python, replace, datatable, na, py-datatable

Hi I am working with the Python datatable package and need to replace all the 'NA' after joining two DT's.

Sample data:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
X = data.table(x=c("c","b"), v=8:7, foo=c(4,2))

X[DT, on="x"]
```

The code below replaces all 1 with 0

```
DT.replace(1, 0)
```

How should I adapt it to replace 'NA'? Or is there maybe an option to change the padding while joining from 'NA' to '0'?
Thank you.

Comment: ```np.nan```. is this what you are looking for? DT.replace(np.nan, 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code using python's data structures :

```
from datatable import dt, f, by, join

DT = dt.Frame(x = ["b"]*3 + ["a"]*3 + ["c"]*3,
          y = [1, 3, 6] * 3,
          v = range(1, 10))

X = dt.Frame({"x":('c','b'),
              "v":(8,7),
              "foo":(4,2)})

X.key="x" # key the ``x`` column

merger = DT[:, :, join(X)]
merger

    x   y   v   v.0 foo
0   b   1   1   7   2
1   b   3   2   7   2
2   b   6   3   7   2
3   a   1   4   NA  NA
4   a   3   5   NA  NA
5   a   6   6   NA  NA
6   c   1   7   8   4
7   c   3   8   8   4
8   c   6   9   8   4
```

The `NA` is also None; it makes it easy to replace with 0 :

```
merger.replace(None, 0)



x   y   v   v.0 foo
0   b   1   1   7   2
1   b   3   2   7   2
2   b   6   3   7   2
3   a   1   4   0   0
4   a   3   5   0   0
5   a   6   6   0   0
6   c   1   7   8   4
7   c   3   8   8   4
8   c   6   9   8   4
```

Comment: Hi, I asked another question regarding datatable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286667/python-datatable-sum-groupby-column-0. Maybe you want to take a look :)