# Python datatable: sum, groupby, column < 0

Tags: python, r, group-by, datatable, py-datatable

Hi I am struggling to translate some R code into Python code.

This is my R code:

```
  df_sum <- df[, .(
    Inflow = sum(subset(Amount, Amount>0)),
    Outflow = sum(subset(Amount, Amount<0)),
    Net = sum(Amount)
  ), by = Account]
```

This is my Python code so far:

```
df_sub = df[:, {'Inflow': dt.sum(dt.f.Amount),
                'Outflow': dt.sum(dt.f.Amount),
                'Net': dt.sum(dt.f.Amount)},
         dt.by('Account')]
```

I don't know how to include the subset for the inflow and outflow columns. Can anyone help?

This is the desired output (generated with R code):

```
     Account Inflow Outflow  Net
1: Account 1    151     -32  119
2: Account 2     51    -226 -175
```

Sample data:

```
{'Account': ['Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 1', 'Account 2', 'Account 2', 'Account 2', 'Account 2', 'Account 2', 'Account 2', 'Account 2', 'Account 2', 'Account 2'], 'Amount': [34, 23, -23, -4, 34, 4, -3, 56, -2, 3, 5, 43, -67, -3, -78, -7, -4, -67]}
```

Comment: Hi Peter. Could you share some sample data as well. Thanks

Comment: I will post sample data shortly

Comment: How can I print the df in a way to copy and paste it here, so you can directly use it?

Comment: hmmmm. paste it the same way you pasted the desired output. If you have it as a datatable, you can do ``frame.to_dict()`` and paste the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ifelse](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dt/ifelse.html) function to replicate your R code:

```
from datatable import dt, f, by, ifelse

   df[:, {"Inflow": dt.sum(ifelse(f.Amount > 0, f.Amount, None)),
          "Outflow": dt.sum(ifelse(f.Amount < 0, f.Amount, None )),
          "Net": dt.sum(f.Amount)}, 
      by("Account")]

     Account    Inflow  Outflow Net
0   Account1       151   −32    119
1   Account2        51   −226  −175
```

Comment: Running this leads to SyntaxError: invalid syntax